# How to find out symmetric encryption algorithm used in PGP encryption (with GPG)?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I would like to be able to check which (inner) symmetric algorithm was used to encrypt a file with GPG using a public key.

Somewhere I've read this can be done with `--list-packets`, so I tried

```
$ gpg --list-packets encrypted_file.asc 
gpg: encrypted with 256-Bit ECDH key, ID 0865135E90D1AF38, created 2020-03-20
      "First Last <first.last@somewhere.net>"
# off=0 ctb=84 tag=1 hlen=2 plen=94
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 18, keyid 0865135E90D1AF38
    data: [263 bits]
    data: [392 bits]
# off=96 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=3 plen=1965 new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 1965
    mdc_method: 2
# off=118 ctb=a3 tag=8 hlen=1 plen=0 indeterminate
:compressed packet: algo=1
# off=120 ctb=cb tag=11 hlen=2 plen=0 partial new-ctb
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 0, name="_CONSOLE",
    raw data: unknown length
```

I thought the symmetric encryption algorithm was encoded in `mdc_method`, but whatever algorithm I use to encrypt, it always displays `2` there. So this doesn't seem to be the correct approach.

How can I find out the symmetric algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to add option `-vv --show-session-key` to the command:

```
$ gpg -vv --show-session-key --list-packets encrypted_file.asc
```

This adds a line like the following to the output:

```
gpg: AES192 encrypted data
gpg: session key: '8:32050C047C47C519E76901EFC47FDFED0CD87CDB85809AFE'
```

The number before the colon (`8` here) is the symmetric algorithm used to encrypt the file contents according to this list (taken from [GnuPG sources](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/common/openpgpdefs.h)):

```
typedef enum
 {
 CIPHER_ALGO_NONE = 0,
 CIPHER_ALGO_IDEA = 1,
 CIPHER_ALGO_3DES = 2,
 CIPHER_ALGO_CAST5 = 3,
 CIPHER_ALGO_BLOWFISH = 4, /* 128 bit */
 /* 5 & 6 are reserved */
 CIPHER_ALGO_AES = 7,
 CIPHER_ALGO_AES192 = 8,
 CIPHER_ALGO_AES256 = 9,
 CIPHER_ALGO_TWOFISH = 10, /* 256 bit */
 CIPHER_ALGO_CAMELLIA128 = 11,
 CIPHER_ALGO_CAMELLIA192 = 12,
 CIPHER_ALGO_CAMELLIA256 = 13
 }
cipher_algo_t;
```

So in this case, the file was encoded using AES-192.

Note that `AES` means AES-128.

Comment: What does it mean when the number before the colon (:) is 9.2, instead of 9? Does it mean it's using some variant of AES256?

Comment: @CuriousLearner That's weird, I haven't seen that yet. Maybe it means AES256-GCM as opposed to AES256-CBC? What does the line above say? Would be worth a new question!

Comment: The line immediately above that says "gpg: AES256.OCB encrypted data". I thought of posting a question, but didn't wanna post the full screenshot as one of those lines contains a session key, and I'm not sure if that information is confidential. I think it may be SHA256 of my passphrase, but I'm not too sure. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I just did some Googling, and it turns out OCB is patented authentication mode, though it is licensed to be used in any purpose other than military. Wow, I didn't know of that. I just used open source Kleopatra (downloaded from www.gnupg4win.org) and configured it to use AES256. I have no idea why Kleopatra would use patented stuff, when non-patented alternatives are easily available.

Comment: @CuriousLearner That’s really interesting. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode) says that OCB is free to be used in open source software, and that the patents were even abandoned in 2021, so this may be why.